# couldn't find module alloy/sync/util

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

> CLI version 3.2.0, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA

the app runs fine in simulator but on device i get an error at start up

> couldn't find module alloy/sync/util

error is correct as in build logs and on alloy directory i do not see util.js 
i only see

```
  [INFO] :   - alloy/sync/localStorage.js 
  [INFO] :   - alloy/sync/properties.js 
  [INFO] :   - alloy/sync/sql.js
```

before upgrade of titanium studio the app worked fine on device 
can some one tell me where did the util.js file go ? or i have add reference to that file ?

and yes my app is using migrations

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild?  Sometimes helps if something weird like this happened.

Comment: still the same issue as it works on simulator

Comment: sync/util.js has since been removed from Alloy, please see this JIRA ticket for more info https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-3375